# Excel VBA Code Issue with Loop Statement - Object Variable or With Block Variable Not Set

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to include a code that would go through column D, search for X entries, and perform necessary actions. This should work until the cell with entry END would be found.
At this point I am getting an error message: Object Variable or With Block Variable Not Set
What I am doing wrong?

```
Sub Example

Range("Cl").Select 
Selection.End(xlDown).Select 
ActiveCell.Offset(l, 1).Range("Al").Select 
ActiveCell.FormulaRlCl = "END"

Dim CellsFound As Range 
 Range("dl").Select 'ActiveCell.Range("al:al000").Select
Set CellsFound = ActiveCell.Range("al:al000") Do Until ActiveCell = "END"
 Cells.Find(What:="X", After:=ActiveCell, Lookin:=xlFormulas, LookAt
:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= True, 
 SearchFormat:=False).Activate
 ActiveCell.Range("Al:Gl").Select Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

 End Sub
```

Comment: You're assuming that the `Find` is successful. Another note - there's probably an easier way to do this with filtering, instead of looping.

Comment: You appear to have a lot of lower case `L`s that should be `1`s in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following will help you achieve your desired outcome, it uses a For Loop to loop through rows, checking the value of the cell in Column D, if X then delete A:G, if END then exit sub:

```
Sub Example()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set the worksheet you are working with, amend as required
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data on Column D

For i = 2 To LastRow
'loop from Row 2 to the last
    If ws.Cells(i, "D").Value = "X" Then ws.Range("A" & i & ":G" & i).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    'if Column D contains "X" then delete A:G on that row
    If ws.Cells(i, "D").Value = "END" Then Exit Sub
    'if Column D contains "END" then Exit Subroutine
Next i
End Sub
```

An alternative to Looping through Rows, would be to Filter them and then delete any visible rows, an example of this is below:

```
Sub Example()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set the worksheet you are working with, amend as required
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data on Column D
ws.Cells.AutoFilter
ws.Range("$A$1:$G$" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="X"
'filter Column 4 (D) for any row where it contains "X"
ws.Range("$A$2:$G$" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete 'Shift:=xlLeft
'delete any visible rows after filtering
ws.ShowAllData
'Clear filter criteria
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Xabier. I saw response from BigBen and used a different approach, instead of looping, sorting and filtering, deleting etc. Thanks for the guidance!

Comment: @OlgierdSzymon I am now curious as to what method you used to delete the specified ranges in the rows that contained X?